# Prolong the tails on the density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am plotting the same **density plot** using **base plotting system** and **ggplot2**.
Density plot in **base plotting system** has smooth tails:

```
d = density(iris$Sepal.Length) 
plot(d)
```

[image]

Density plot in **ggplot2** has chopped tails:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Is there any way to force ggplot2 to plot density plot similar to base plotting system (with smooth tails)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the density and use `xlim` to set range from it:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- density(iris$Sepal.Length)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  xlim(range(d$x))
```

**Plot**

[image: plot density with full tails]